# Matlab- Combinations for subsets of a set

Tags: arrays, matlab, set, combinations, subset

Hi may I know how i can perform this using matlab? 
I tried nchoosek but only works on 1 type of combination. I would like to output all together in array

Let S={a,b,c,d,e}

I would like to get combinations as such which start from 3 combinations:

the 3-combinations : {a,b,c} , {a,b,d} , {a,b,e} , {a,c,d} , {a,c,e} , {a,d,e} 
the 4-combinations : {a,b,c,d} , {a,b,c,e} , {a,c,d,e}
the 5-combinations : {a,b,c,d,e}

So the output would be like this:
 {a,b,c} 
 {a,b,d} 
 {a,b,e} 
 {a,c,d} 
 {a,c,e} 
 {a,d,e}
{a,b,c,d} 
{a,b,c,e} 
{a,c,d,e}
{a,b,c,d,e}
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a loop there or `arrayfun` which is just a compact way to express such a loopy approach and not a vectorized approach -

```
combs = arrayfun(@(x) nchoosek(S,x),3:numel(S),'Uniform',0)
```

The output would be a cell array with each cell representing values for each combination. So, when you run the code, you would get -

```
>> combs{1}
ans =
     2     7     4
     2     7     1
     2     7     9
     2     4     1
     2     4     9
     2     1     9
     7     4     1
     7     4     9
     7     1     9
     4     1     9
```

which would be your `3-combinations` set.

```
>> combs{2}
ans =
     2     7     4     1
     2     7     4     9
     2     7     1     9
     2     4     1     9
     7     4     1     9
```

would be your `4-combinations` set and so on.

Comment: I think you meant <<`4-combinations` set>> in the last line.

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar Sorry yeah that's what I meant. Thank you on pointing out that one!